# Sometimes a website is not able to load completely when multiple URL is passed in loop in FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to pass on multiple URLs by fetching them from an excel sheet one by one in a loop and trying to open the website using FirefoxDriver. Sometimes when a URL is passed, the website fails to load completely and the process gets stuck in the middle. There is no issue with the URL. What can be the reason, is it because of passing multiple URLs on FirefoxDriver in the manner done by me?
Following is the code used:

```
int lastr=sheet.getLastRowNum();
 for(int i=1;i<=lastr;i++)
{
 row = sheet.getRow(i);
 cell=row.getCell(0);
 System.out.print(i);
 System.out.println(" "+cell.toString());      
driver.get(cell.toString());
try{
if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]")).getAttribute("id").equals("newBreadCrumb"))
System.out.println("Pass");
else
System.out.println("Fail"); 
}
catch(Exception e)
{System.out.println("Pass")}

}
```

Comment: "Sometimes when a URL is passed, the website fails to load completely and the process gets stuck in the middle." - Does this mean it fails, or does your browser just hang?

Comment: I mean the process doesn't move further, The browser loads the website and the processing spinner keeps moving in the browser title tab.

Comment: What is your WebDriver's wait time set for?

Comment: The wait time is 5 secs but as far as I know for loading a website there is no need to set a wait time as by default webdriver waits for substantial amount of time and this problem comes sometimes not always.

Comment: Ok. Because Selenium has a default (or shorter if explicitlystated) wait time, if the driver does not find the element within that time, it will fail the test with an Element not found error. Because your test doesn't seem to be failing, but the browser hangs, I suspect something wonky is happening with your driver. It happened to me once when I tried to open a second browser on a second WebDriver soon after starting the first driver. My solution was to put a pause between the starting of the first and second drivers. That doesn't seem to be your issue, but hopefully it gives you some ideas...